# Seeking Digital Terrain Map of Israel

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Where can I find an open detailed DEM/DTM model of Israel for some research?

I have found:

- https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata
- https://www.gov.il/en/departments/general/israel-and-regions-aerial-photo-map
- https://www.gov.il/en/departments/general/relief-map-of-israel-2

This one below is 25m and is nice (from the link), but a pdf, not the raster, is provided.

[image: Israel Hall et al 1990s]

Comment: What is the highest-resolution raster you've been able to find so far?

Comment: the one in diva gis... not sure what's the resolution, but it's poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the SRTM 1 arc (30m) by going through this web GUI https://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/ to get the links. You need an account on NASA Earthdata (link in the GUI to create one)

Israel covered by 5 SRTM tiles e.g screencapture below

[image: SRTM grid tiles 1 arc centered on Israel]

You will need to merge these 5 tiles. You may use "gdalbuildvrt" (https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) to do so and then convert the resulting VRT with "gdal_translate" https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html Both command line utilities are provided by GDAL. You may also use QGIS to do the same using a GUI but "I do not know where you are starting from" concerning your skillsets.

PS: All tools mentioned are Open Source and the data is also available freely after creating your NASA account.

Answer (score 3):

The resolution of the DEM from diva GIS is 30 seconds, which is about 800 to 900 m at 30 degrees latitude. That raster is aggregated from CGIAR-CSI source data, which is accurate to 3 seconds. That's about 90m resolution. You can get that 90m DEM [here](https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/). It's broken up into separate tiles, and Israel falls across the dividing line between tiles, so you'll need to download multiple tiles.

Comment: Super, thaks so much. Any ideas as to the 25m raster that was developed by Hall et al in the 90's?

Answer (score 2):

If you are an academic you may be able to source it from [land info](http://www.landinfo.com/country-israel.html) or purchase it from them , they appear to be offering it even down to 5m resolution?

Comment: That is what I would recommend is to find out if any higher education has it.